# Unable to ssh to the aws Amazon Unix session

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an instance of aws-Amazon Linux on my vpc and when i tried to connect(ssh) to it from my windows instance, i get the below error-

```
---------------------------
PuTTY Fatal Error
---------------------------
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I used the below syntax to connect to my instance-

```
"c:\Program Files\Putty\PUTTY.EXE" -ssh ec2-user@10.0.0.26 -i c:\Shared\mykey1.pem
```

**Do suggest on how this can be fixed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the key into a format putty can use:

1. Start PuttyGen
2. Under Type of key to generate, select SSH-2 RSA.
3. Click Load. By default, PuTTYgen displays only files with the extension .ppk. To locate your .pem file, select the option to display files of all types
4. Select your .pem file for the key pair that you specified when you launch your instance, and then click Open. Click OK to dismiss the confirmation dialog box
5. Click Save private key to save the key in the format that PuTTY can use. PuTTYgen displays a warning about saving the key without a passphrase. Click Yes.
6. Specify the same name for the key that you used for the key pair (for example, my-key-pair). PuTTY automatically adds the .ppk file extension.

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html) is the documentation.

Comment: Noel, why didnt Amazon mention these steps of connecting to their instance? They recommend to connect to the instance via a pem and not by ppk. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: If its solved your problem you can accept the answer by clicking the tick below the vote buttons. Amazon did mention these steps that is why you can find it in the documentation.

Comment: Noel, yes, i could now see the steps. My bad that i didnt go through the documentation steps which you mentioned..

Comment: You still haven't [accepted the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)... if this solved your problem its the generally accepted practice to accept the answer